# Div disappears in production, but not in testing with webkit filter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, so this is the problem that I am having. I have applied a blur filter to an image on my website. Whenever I first go to the site (production) everything loads fine. All of the content is there. However, when I navigate to another page on the site and then back to the homepage, the image which was blurred disappears and isnt rendered. I'm not quite sure why this is happening. The odd thing is that this doesn't happen when I test it out on a server on my local machine, it is only in production.

Here is the html

```html
  <div class="stuff" style="display: block; text-align: center;">
  <div id = "owl-demo" class="owl-carousel hidden-sm hidden-xs ">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="blur">
      <%=link_to(image_tag('scifi.jpeg', :alt => "Slide1", :class => "img-responsive", :style => "height: 600px;"), contact_path )%>
        </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="padding-bottom: 110px; text-align: center;">
              <%=image_tag('logo.png', :alt => "Slide1", :class => "img-responsive", :style => "height: 300px; width: auto; display: block; margin:0 auto;")%>
              <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

And The CSS for the image. (note, I am using owl-carousel, however it is a single image, not an actual carousel.)

```css
#owl-demo .item img{
  opacity: 1.0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.blur{
  filter: blur(2px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -5px -10px -10px -5px;
}
```

Comment: I think it is an asp.net issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is how you have setup your carousel, as each individual asset needs its own item class. You have indicated the active (initial) asset to be displayed but once you refresh or bounce to a different page then things get scrambled.

To work properly, you must ensure each asset is contained in its own <div class="item"> like so:

```
<div id="owl-demo">
  <div class="item active"><img src="assets/scifi.jpg" alt="SciFi"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Logo"></div>
</div>
```

As long you have committed all your assets to your Dev and Prod enviro and used the owl carousel appropriately them the problem should be resolved.